# Intel 2015 compiler bug, RAII destruction not correct, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, icc

I've got a test case where I have a class with 3 subobjects (`A`, `B` and `C`), and the 2nd subobject `B` throws an exception during construction. As I understand C++, the compiler should rewind the construction of the big class and destroy the 1st object `A`, but not the 2nd (`B`) or 3rd (`C`) objects.

What I see is that if I use "In-class initialization" of the first object `A`, then instead of the first object `A` getting destroyed, *the 3rd object `C` gets destroyed*. Of course it is **VERY BAD** to destroy an object that has not been constructed!  If, for example, `C` was a `std:unique_ptr<T>`, it will probably signal a segmentation violation when it tries to free a garbage pointer.

If I use old school "member initialization", then this problem doesn't happen.

I don't see this with gcc 4.8

Here's the code.  The class `D` exposes the bug. The class `E` should have identical function, but it does not expose the bug.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct A {
    A(const string& x) : x_(x) { cout << "A::A()" << (void*)this <<endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "A::~A() " << (void*)this<< endl;}
    string x_;
};

struct B {
    B(const A& a)  { cout << "B::B()" << endl; throw "dead"; }
    ~B() { cout << "B::~B()" << endl;}
};

struct C {
    C()  { cout << "C::C()" << endl; }
    ~C() { cout << "C::~C()" << endl;}
};


struct D  {
    A a{"foo"}; // "new school In-class initialization"
    B b{a};
    C c;
    D() { cout <<"D::D()" << endl; }
    ~D() { cout <<"D::~D()" << endl; }
};

struct E {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    E()
        :a{"foo"}  // "old school member initialization"
        ,b(a)
        { cout <<"E::E()" << endl; }
    ~E() { cout <<"E::~E()" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
   try {
       D d;
   }
   catch(...)
   {
       cout << "got exception" << endl;
   }

   try {
       E e;
   }
   catch(...)
   {
       cout << "got exception" << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Here is the output. I expect to see `A` constructed, `B` partially constructed then throws, then `A` destroyed, but that is not what I see for the `D` case.

```
$ icpc -std=c++11 test.cpp
$ ./a.out
A::A()0x7fffe0a5ee90
B::B()
C::~C()
got exception

A::A()0x7fffe0a5eea0
B::B()
A::~A() 0x7fffe0a5eea0
got exception
```

-- update --

The section of the [standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4431.pdf) that describes what should happen is 15.2.3

> For an object of class type of any storage duration whose
>   initialization or destruction is terminated by an exception, the
>   destructor is invoked for each of the object’s fully constructed
>   subobjects, that is, for each subobject for which the principal
>   constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution and the destructor has
>   not yet begun execution, except that in the case of destruction, the
>   variant members of a union-like class are not destroyed. The
>   subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of
>   their construction. Such destruction is sequenced before entering a
>   handler of the function-try-block of the constructor or destructor, if
>   any.

Comment: For those that are interested, the presence of a `try/catch` wrapper makes a difference in stack unwinding and there are inconsistencies in compilers  : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137693/if-initialization-or-destruction-is-terminated-by-an-exception-which-is-not-hand

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely a compiler bug, and you've answered your own question with the correct reference from the standard: [except.ctor]/3, with added emphasis:

> For an object of class type of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction is terminated by an
>   exception, the destructor is invoked for each of the object’s **fully constructed** subobjects, that is, for each
>   subobject for which the **principal constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution** and the destructor has not
>   yet begun execution, except that in the case of destruction, the variant members of a union-like class are not
>   destroyed. The subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their construction. Such
>   destruction is sequenced before entering a handler of the function-try-block of the constructor or destructor,
>   if any.

Where:

> The *principal constructor* is the first constructor invoked
>   in the construction of an object (that is, not a target constructor for that object’s construction).

`C` has not been fully constructed - its principal constructor has not even been called yet - so it's destructor should not be called yet.

Comment: I was worried that I did something stupid, causing UB, after which all bets are off.

Comment: @MarkLakata Everything looks perfectly reasonable from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Intel has confirmed this is an issue.

The compiler I used was

```
icpc (ICC) 15.0.2 20150121
```

You can follow the Intel forum for updates on when it is resolved.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1827356